# How do I make Google chrome full screen appear in the 2nd display while the tabs remain in the main monitor?

Tags: google-chrome

How do I make Google chrome full screen appear in the 2nd display while the tabs remain in the main monitor?

I want to illustrate my question in this link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QdGXsZWuX4p8-N-eqeTXoKi0ytnv6nYNHB51FK16CJo

Thanks for your answer. I'll appreciate it much. Thanks for taking the time.

I'm actually working now with Google solely when having my presentations. I'll be presenting using Google slides, and I want to present other web pages without having to obviously to drag and drop the tabs in the 2nd screen. When working with MS Powerpoint, that's possible. You simply click 'present slide show' and the slides automatically appear in the 2nd screen while the controls remain in the main screen. I hope there's a function for that as well in Google, where you can click on tabs and get their full screen views on the 2nd screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but if you want the projector to copy your monitor screen you can right click anywhere on your desktop and select Display Settings, then it should open a window where you can see how many monitors are plugged into your pc.

Normally the projector should be listed as a second monitor, if not you can use the Identify button for your pc to detect it. Once you have both monitors identified, scroll down until you see something about Multiple Monitors and select Duplicate in the settings and there you go :)

If want you want was to have only your Tab1 on the projector, usually projectors have a remote control, and it should have a Freeze button, which you can use to freeze the projector on Tab1 while you browse any tab on your main screen.

I hope that this comment is helpful to you :)

Edit : (answering your edit)

Well, I don't think there is such a function on Google Chrome for now. But what you can do, if you have the time, is preparing your Chrome window in advance, opening every tab in the order you want to present them, then press F11 to enable full screen and switch from tab to tab with Ctrl+Tab for left to right, and Ctrl+Shift+Tab if you need to come on earlier slides/tabs (right to left). Hopefully this solution is more convenient for you :)